# create different folders for different type of users and to create a filter for that

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, filter, directory

I want to create a neat project that can help me in future to update. I am about to complete my project and now I want to place different files in different folders based on their privileges like a folder named Admin where all corresponding .jsp and/or servelt having Admin privilege are placed together and also how can i create a filter to check whether a user is authorized to access any jsp and/or servlet in that folder or not. *I am denied to upload my projects image due to lack of reputations*..

this is how usually projects are:

> > ### Web Pages
> >
> > certain **Admin** .jsp's
> >
> > ### Source
> >
> > certain **Admin** servlets

I want to place all the Admin jsp/servlet in a folder and create a filter to check whether a user is authorized or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Upto my knowledge**

---

That is not possible directly for **Servlets** different package can be created and similarly a folder can be created for **jsp** and to control these a **filter** can be created but you need to ***filter-map*** those independently.. So a better way is to check on the top of servlet or jsp whether a user is authenticated to view it or not...